# css form - radio button placement

Tags: html, css

I am currently learning html/css and would like to develop my first web form. However, I am having issues placing my radio buttons next to the associated label.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3sPNH/16/)

I assume I have to create a .radio style in my css. However, I am not certain what to do.

```
<form id="contactform" class="rounded" method="post" action="">

<h3>Equipment Procurement Form</h3>

    <p>Use this form to submit requests to Medical Physics for new equipment</p>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="Directorate">Directorate</label>
        <input type="text" class="input" name="Directorate" id="Directorate" />
        <p class="hint">Enter your directorate.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="Department">Department:</label>
        <input type="text" class="input" name="Department" id="Department" />
        <p class="hint">Enter your department.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="Request">Equipment Requested:</label>
        <textarea class="input textarea" name="Request" id="Request"></textarea>
        <p class="hint">Summarise equipment request..</p>
    </div>

    <div class="radio">  
        <input id="Capital" type="radio" name="Capital" value="Capital">  
            <label for="Capital">Capital
                <span class="small">&#62;&pound;5000 (inc VAT)</span></label>  
        <input id="Capital" type="radio" name="Capital" value="Revenue">  
        <label for="Capital">Revenue
            <span class="small">&#60;&pound;5000 (inc VAT)</span></label>   
    </div>  

    <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: You can just use this to make a radio button formed within the group: <input type="radio" name="capital"/> Capital //this should put a radio button next to capital

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this http://jsfiddle.net/3sPNH/13/ . I hope this is how you want. Just placed the `input` inside.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Don't suppose you know why my second set of radio buttons don't fall on the next line?

Comment: You mean you have another set of two radio buttons apart from this ?

Comment: use this  .field { float: left;} .

Comment: Let me know if its fine ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<form id="contactform" class="rounded" method="post" action="">

<h3>Equipment Procurement Form</h3>

<p>Use this form to submit requests to Medical Physics for new equipment</p>
<div class="field">
    <label for="Directorate">Directorate</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="Directorate" id="Directorate" />
    <p class="hint">Enter your directorate.</p>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="Department">Department:</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="Department" id="Department" />
    <p class="hint">Enter your department.</p>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="Request">Equipment Requested:</label>
    <textarea class="input textarea" name="Request" id="Request"></textarea>
    <p class="hint">Summarise equipment request..</p>
</div>
<div class="radio">  
    <label><input id="Capital" type="radio" name="Capital" value="Capital">  
        Capital
            <span class="small">&#62;&pound;5000 (inc VAT)</span></label>  

    <label>
        <input id="Capital" type="radio" name="Capital" value="Revenue">
        Revenue
        <span class="small">&#60;&pound;5000 (inc VAT)</span></label>   
</div>  

<input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button" value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You put the radio buttons outside of the label, it will hold them together if you put them in.

```
<div class="radio">  
        <label for="Capital">Capital
        <input id="Capital" type="radio" name="Capital" value="Capital">  
        <span class="small">&#62;&pound;5000 (inc VAT)</span></label>  

         <label for="Capital">Revenue
         <input id="Capital" type="radio" name="Capital" value="Revenue"> 
         <span class="small">&#60;&pound;5000 (inc VAT)</span></label>   
    </div>
```